# Unable to filter out a specific value for a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I want to filter out a specific value(9999) that appears many times from a subset of my dataset. This is what I have done so far but I'm not sure how to filter out all the 9999 values.

```
import pandas as pd
import statistics  

df=pd.read_csv('Area(2).txt',delimiter='\t')
```

Initially, this is what a part of my dataset for 30 days (containing 600+ values) looks like below. I'm just showing the first two rows here.

```
   No    Date              Time  Rand   Col  Value
0  2161  1  4 1991         0:00   181    1   9999
1  2162  1  4 1991         1:00   181    2   9999
```

Now I wanted to select the range of numbers under the column "Values" between 23-25 April. So I did the following:

```
df5=df.iloc[528:602,5]
print(df5)
```

The range of values I get for 23-25 April looks like this:

```
528    9999
529    9999
530    9999
531    9999
532    9999

597    9999
598    9999
599    9999
600    9999
601    9999
Name: Value, Length: 74, dtype: int64
```

I want to filter out all 9999 values from this subset, I have tried a number of ways to get rid of these values but I keep getting **IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds** so I am unable to get rid of 9999 and do further work like finding the variance and standard deviation with the selected subset.

If this helps, I also tried to filter out 9999 in the beginning and it looked like this:

```
df2=df[df.Value!=9999]
print(df2)
       No        Date         Time  Rand  Col  Value
6    2167   1  4 1991         6:00   181    7    152
7    2168   1  4 1991         7:00   181    8    178
8    2169   1  4 1991         8:00   181    9    239
9    2170   1  4 1991         9:00   181   10    296
10   2171   1  4 1991        10:00   181   11    337
..    ...         ...          ...   ...  ...    ...
638  2799  27  4 1991        14:00   234    3    193
639  2800  27  4 1991        15:00   234    4    162
640  2801  27  4 1991        16:00   234    5    144
641  2802  27  4 1991        17:00   234    6    151
642  2803  27  4 1991        18:00   234    7    210

[351 rows x 6 columns]
```

Then I tried to obtain the range of column values between 23 April - 25 April by trying what I did below but I always get **IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds**

```
df6=df2.iloc[528:602,5]
print(df6)
```

How I can properly filter out the value I mentioned and obtain the subset of the dataset that I need?

Comment: Try `df.iloc[528:602,:]`

Comment: I hope this is readable, I don't know how to format the commands in comments. Did you mean to try it in this way?

df=pd.read_csv('Area(2).txt',delimiter='\t') ,
df2=df[df.Value!=9999],       
df6=df2.iloc[528:602,:] 

.If i try this on the subset that has already been filtered out I get this output:

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [No, Date,         Time, Rand, Col, Value]
Index: []

Comment: @TomRon Okay I misunderstood what you said. I tried doing what you mentioned df7=df.iloc[528:602,:], and then I filtered out 9999 using df8=df7[df7.Value!=9999] and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
      No        Date   Time  Rand  Col  Value
0   2161   1  4 1991   0:00   181    1   9999
1   2162   1  4 1991   1:00   181    2   9999
2   2167   1  4 1991   6:00   181    7    152
3   2168   1  4 1991   7:00   181    8    178
4   2169   1  4 1991   8:00   181    9    239
5   2170   1  4 1991   9:00   181   10    296
6   2171   1  4 1991  10:00   181   11    337
7   2799  27  4 1991  14:00   234    3    193
8   2800  27  4 1991  15:00   234    4    162
9   2801  27  4 1991  16:00   234    5    144
10  2802  27  4 1991  17:00   234    6    151
11  2803  27  4 1991  18:00   234    7    210
```

First, let's make a proper datetime index:

```
# Your dates are pretty scuffed, there was some formatting to make them make sense...
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.Date.str.split().apply(lambda x: f'{x[1].zfill(2)}-{x[0].zfill(2)}-{x[2]}') + ' ' + df.Time)
df.drop(['Date', 'Time'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This gives:

```
                       No  Rand  Col  Value
1991-04-01 00:00:00  2161   181    1   9999
1991-04-01 01:00:00  2162   181    2   9999
1991-04-01 06:00:00  2167   181    7    152
1991-04-01 07:00:00  2168   181    8    178
1991-04-01 08:00:00  2169   181    9    239
1991-04-01 09:00:00  2170   181   10    296
1991-04-01 10:00:00  2171   181   11    337
1991-04-27 14:00:00  2799   234    3    193
1991-04-27 15:00:00  2800   234    4    162
1991-04-27 16:00:00  2801   234    5    144
1991-04-27 17:00:00  2802   234    6    151
1991-04-27 18:00:00  2803   234    7    210
```

Then, we can easily fulfill your conditions (replace the dates with your own desired range).

```
df[df.Value.ne(9999)].loc['1991-04-01':'1991-04-01']
# df[df.Value.ne(9999)].loc['1991-04-23':'1991-04-25']
```

Output:

```
                       No  Rand  Col  Value
1991-04-01 06:00:00  2167   181    7    152
1991-04-01 07:00:00  2168   181    8    178
1991-04-01 08:00:00  2169   181    9    239
1991-04-01 09:00:00  2170   181   10    296
1991-04-01 10:00:00  2171   181   11    337
```